# Searching and replacing values in an object with multiple properties......C#

Tags: c#

I have an object that gets populated when i make a call to the database. The results being returned contain the literal string "NULL". I have about 40 properties in my object thats gets populated. How do I loop replace all objects with the string "NULL" with an empty string WITHOUT doing it the archaic way like so:

```
var ttt =  GetTheData();

foreach (var t in ttt)
{
    if (t.AddressLine1 == "NULL") t.AddressLine1 = string.Empty;
    if (t.City == "NULL") t.City = string.Empty;
   //so forth and so on
}
```

And no I am not in control of the data coming back. So yes the logical way is to fix it at the db level. I'm hoping someone has encountered this and found a better solution. I'm using .NET 4.0 btw. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show what the structure of the Object is.. is it in a class..? if so I can provide you with a simple quick way to do this provided the type is of Class... also if this is an object.. why can't you use the string.Replace function to do this.. can you show what `ttt` looks like uploading a screen shot from the quick watch..? is ttt a datatable..? if so this is even easier to accomplish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var ttt =  GetTheData();

foreach (var t in ttt)
{
    var properties = t.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach(var p in properties){
       if(p.PropertyType.Name.Equals("String")){
          if(p.GetValue(t,null).ToString() == "NULL")
             p.SetValue(t,string.Empty,null);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: read the question again there is a difference between `null` and `"NULL"`
should be checking for 
`if (p.PropertyType == typeof(string)`

Comment: @MethodMan look at my answer again. I don't know which properties he is interested in. It's up to him to update my solution to suit his need.

Comment: @neo - i love your answer, i just need to get the type of p in properties because the compiler won't compile your code as is, and when i cast it to a string, if p is not of type string, the app throws an error.

Comment: @BoundForGlory I updated my answer. It checks if property type is string, then it checks if value is "NULL"

Comment: @neo - on this line if (p.GetValue(p, null).ToString() == "NULL") i get "Object does not match target type". I'm looking this error up

Comment: @BoundForGlory I updated. It should work now. Parameter should have been t instead of p.

Comment: @neo - yes it worked, but i had to tweak it just a little. there were actual null values in the returned data, so the ToString() was blowing up. So I added this var chkVal = p.GetValue(specialAccount, null) as string; and checked if chkVal == "NULL". Thank you so much :)

Comment: Not a fan of reflection for this but that's an opinion so nothing wrong with the answer. If you go with this approach, do take the time to make sure there's not a meaningful performance hit. If there is, you can probably still make the overall idea work. For example, pulling t.GetType().GetProperties() and all the string type checking out of the loop, caching this out once figured out per type, and then enumerating only those cached values when doing GetValue/SetValue. Even then, if dealing with thousands of records/properties this is something to concern yourself with.

Answer (score 0):

There's an alternative to a loop: use implicit operators, and use a class to wrap strings:

```
public sealed class NullableString
{
    private readonly string _value;

    private NullableString(string value)
    {
         _value = value;
    }

    private string Value { get { return _value; } }

    public static implicit operator string(NullableString nullableString)
    {
          return nullableString.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator NullableString(string value)
    {
          if(value == "NULL")
               value = string.Empty;

          return new NullableString(value);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
          return Value;
    }
}
```

Now, your class should declare its properties this way:

```
public class YourClass
{
     public NullableString AddressLine { get; set; }
}
```

Since `NullableString` has an implicit operator to implicitly convert a regular `string` to `NullableString` and viceversa, if a regular `string` comes with `NULL` literal it will turned into `string.Empty` automatically:

```
YourClass some = new YourClass();
some.AddressLine = "NULL"; // This will store an empty string  (i.e. "")
```

And you can set a `string`-typed variable:

```
string addressLine = some.AddressLine;
```

This solution might need some refactoring but it will be more performant than using reflection.

Comment: If the class is generated by a tool like EF, should OP change all string properties to `NullableString` manually ?

Comment: @Eser Search&Replace to the rescue. BTW, I don't see a [tag:entity-framework] on the question......

Comment: @Eser both you and me don't know actual OP's domain. Maybe OP has less than 10 classes or 300. BTW, what if there's nothing generated and OP is using Code First? Or what if OP is using a micro ORM like Dapper? Instead of guessing just consider I wanted to add an alternative to reflection!

Comment: @Eser BTW I didn't see the "generated by a tool" when I suggested a *Search and replace*. There wouldn't be a solution because each re-generation, model update or whatever would destroy the changes.

Comment: @Eser Anyway, again, since we don't know if OP is using an OR/M, and if OP is using some one we don't know which one in detail, how OP is using it... At least, the implicit operator approach isn't that bad. Also reflection approach sounds bad and it's bloating the domain while addressing the issue in the database should be the definitive solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, since you said you have no control over "GetTheData" and it's return type (and it seems you're probably using some sort of ORM) would be to create a sql view that does what you need thereby insulating yourself from the "NULL" weirdness. Map your ORM to the view instead of whatever it's currently mapped to. Of course, if the source changes a lot this would not be fun to manage.

Would a simple extension method on string meet your needs? E.g. t.Address1.NullAsEmpty()?